# React native ios build failed showing multiple instances of the same simulator and same UDID, "com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler" flagged

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, codegen

```
2023-04-10 12:54:39.743 xcodebuild[37229:209830] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F74E3465-A58E-4B17-BF2B-1CB79F225F2F, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F74E3465-A58E-4B17-BF2B-1CB79F225F2F, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/devansh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RN_App-eibylxcwymbqneczxtsodzlvaqxg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.o /Users/devansh/Desktop/rn-temp-engin2.0/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

When trying to build the ios project in a React native project, I encountered this error. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the XCode_14.3, followed the commands to clear the npm cache, deleted Pods, cleared Derived_Data of XCode, and even deleted the devices which were highlighted, but this error is shown with every next device in the list shown by `xcrun simctl list devices`.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the xcode to 14.2, so it worked normally

Comment: Xcode versions are in sync with macOS versions updates, so it shows on the apple developer site that for macOS Ventura we need Xcode 14.3* versions