# React Native Ios build: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default

Tags: ios, xcode14.3

I recently bought an M2 MacBook Pro and it builds on Android but I got this error building react native on iOS. Is there a solution?

## Error

```
2023-04-16 16:11:02.557 xcodebuild[7974:97685] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D9F3FC26-B488-469A-A928-A8511F2FDAC0, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D9F3FC26-B488-469A-A928-A8511F2FDAC0, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 13 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/abel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleProject-dkxmrcwvisfquleuhrctlqklsdvb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Yoga.o /Users/abel/Desktop/SampleProject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

# npx react-native info

System:
    OS: macOS 13.3.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
    Memory: 167.09 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.04.10.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0 - /Users/abel/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.18 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

You recently downgraded cocoapod from 1.20 to 1.10

Comment: I downgraded the xcode to 14.2, so it worked normally

Answer (score 1):

I have asked the same question and here are my system specs.
Here is the link to my question!
[React native ios build failed showing multiple instances of the same simulator and same UDID, "com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler" flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975143/react-native-ios-build-failed-showing-multiple-instances-of-the-same-simulator-a)

[image: System Info]

Someone has recommended to downgrade the XCode from 14.3 to 14.2, and the way I did it was to download it from the website instead of getting it from Appstore.app

Comment: To downgrade the xcode version is not an actual solution, except for a time being it may help out.